# Java - JTextBox

Tags: java

На языке Java как написать код, чтобы когда нажать клажишу Enter, курсор из одного текст бокса фокусировать на другую.

Comment: @Arsen Вопросы по программированию правильно спрашивать на [ХэшКоде](http://hashcode.ru).

Answer (score 2):

А точно `JTextBox`? Может `javax.swing.JTextArea`? У него есть свойство setFocusable.